# python code for a sum of powers of 2 of an integer

Tags: python-3.x

I am wondering how to write python code for sum of powers of 2 of an integer.
For example,
I want to define an integer, such as 10
I then want python to out put in a list [8,2] (because (2^3)+(2^1))
I am using python 3.5.1. 
Thank you

Comment: Could you at least show some code you have worked on for this.

Comment: If you can convert the integer to binary, getting the list you want should be easy. Stack Overflow is not here to do your homework for you though, so you'll probably need to show what you've tried and describe what issues you're having before you'll get many answers.